Магически исчезает data в state после функции proxy_service
Пробовал уже все, что смог придумать, и работу фильтров (ProxyFilter(), ProxyGeoFilter()), делал логирование всего, проверял, очищаются ли где-то стейты, да даже пробовал заменять одинарные кавычки на двойные.
И, тем не менее, ничего не работает, после функции proxy_service, в функции proxy_geo, data = await state.get_data() ничего не выдает.
@router_catalog_proxy.callback_query(F.data == 'catalog_proxy')
async def catalog_proxy(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(select_state.catalog_proxy)

    catalog = callback.data
    catalog = catalog[8:]
    await state.update_data(catalog=catalog)

    data = await state.get_data()
    lang = data.get('lang')

    keyboard_accounts = create_keyboard_proxy(lang)

    await callback.message.edit_text(local(lang=lang, text='catalog_proxy', catalog=catalog),
                                     reply_markup=keyboard_accounts.as_markup())


@router_catalog_proxy.callback_query(ProxyFilter())
async def proxy_service(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(select_state.proxy_service)

    service = callback.data
    await state.update_data(service=service)

    data = await state.get_data()
    lang = data.get('lang')
    catalog = data.get('catalog')

    account_type_keyboard = create_keyboard_proxy_geo(lang=lang, key_prefix=service)

    await callback.message.edit_text(local(lang=lang, text='proxy_service', catalog=catalog, service=service),
                                     reply_markup=account_type_keyboard.as_markup())


@router_catalog_proxy.callback_query(ProxyGeoFilter())
async def proxy_geo(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(select_state.proxy_geo)

    geo_of_proxy = callback.data
    await state.update_data(geo_of_proxy=geo_of_proxy)

    data = await state.get_data()
    lang = data.get('lang')
    service = data.get('service')
    catalog = data.get('catalog')

    keyboard_account_qty = create_keyboard_proxy_qty(lang=lang)

    await callback.message.edit_text(local(lang=lang, text='proxy_qty', catalog=catalog, service=service,
                                           proxy_geo=geo_of_proxy),
                                     reply_markup=keyboard_account_qty.as_markup())

